# ReactJS Class Component Rendering Twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

Very simple example: My App.js file reads

```
import React from 'react';
import Test from './component/Test';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Test/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

and my Test.js file reads

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Test extends Component {

    render() {
        console.log('rendered')
        return null
    }
}

export default Test
```

In the console, 'rendered' is always printed twice. Why?

Comment: A couple more console.log tests: the App.js function is indeed only called once. The Test.js componentDidMount() is also definitely called once

Comment: Does this have something to do with me running the app in development mode on localhost:3000/ ? And if that's the case, can/should this behavior be changed?

Comment: This is normal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136836/react-component-render-is-called-multiple-times-when-pushing-new-url

Comment: Thanks! I'm curious though as to what's going on 'behind the scenes' i.e. what is the benefit of this being a normal behavior?

Comment: I’m quite new to it myself but there are certain lifecycle methods that get called more than once. I think some are render, componentDidMount, ect. These will each get called which is why render is called twice, at least to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is **React.StrictMode**.
React.StrictMode is a wrapper introduced in version 16.3.0 back in 2018 and in 16.8.0 it is applied also for hooks.

**Code:**
Check index.js for the below code

```
 <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
```

**React.StrictMode**
cannot spot side-effects at once, but it can help us find them by intentionally invoking twice some key functions.

These functions are:

- Class component constructor, render, and shouldComponentUpdate methods
- Class component static getDerivedStateFromProps method
- Function component bodies
- State updater functions (the first argument to setState)
- Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer

Please check this blog
https://mariosfakiolas.com/blog/my-react-components-render-twice-and-drive-me-crazy/

Comment: Thank you! This is a great explanation

Comment: Welcome.. please accept my answer as the best suited answer.