# Why does the react function execute twice, but the console only prints once？

Tags: javascript, reactjs

everyone.
I'm learning react recently. I learned a lesson
As this [link](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17786) says, the react function loads twice.
But when I verified it, I found that it did load twice, but the Chrome browser only printed once. I wonder why?
Here is the code I verified.

```
let count = 0;
function App() {
const [state, setState] = useState(1);

count++;
console.log(count);
console.log(`I have run ${count} time(s)!`);
return (
   <div>
     <button onClick={() => setState((e) => e + 1)}>{state}</button>
   </div>
);
```

Here is the result of chrome execution[image]

I think chrome should concole.log

1
App.js:9 I have run 1 time(s)!
2
App.js:9 I have run 2 time(s)!

I want to know why.
Thank you.

Comment: ["Starting with React 17, React automatically modifies the console methods like console.log() to silence the logs in the second call to lifecycle functions. However, it may cause undesired behavior in certain cases where a workaround can be used."](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) (no element to jump to, need to search)

Comment: Why do you think this function would run twice?

Comment: Its because of the use of setState(), try removing it and see the change. For more details ref this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136836/react-component-render-is-called-multiple-times-when-pushing-new-url

Comment: Is strict mode on by default or something now?

Comment: Still opt-in with next.js https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/react-strict-mode

Comment: React is allowed to run these functions multiple times, for arbitrary reasons. While the dominant cases are strict mode and debug, it's not certain that it wouldn't happen elsewhere too (that's why the before-mentioned do it, to highlight bugs, so one doesn't have to wait for the potentially rare occasion). Function component functions must be pure (among some details, idempotent), so when you write proper code, it should not matter.

Comment: Right, but that doesn't mean the function will never only run once. It running once is not a surprising result. Some people might be surprised if it ran twice, but of course that is not a surprising result either.